# Converting Mechanical Turk bounding boxes to JSON for object detection

Tags: amazon-web-services, object-detection, bounding-box, mechanicalturk, amazon-sagemaker

I am looking to have several 1000 images annotated with bounding boxes on MTurk. When reading the following tutorial (https://blog.mturk.com/tutorial-annotating-images-with-bounding-boxes-using-amazon-mechanical-turk-42ab71e5068a), it seems like the output of a task will look like the following:

```
The Worker with ID A39ECJ12CY7TE9 gave the answer 
[{'left': 369, 'top': 47, 'width': 151, 'height': 160, 'label': 'stop sign'}]
```

For my object detection model in Sagemaker, I need a dataset of training images in jpg in one folder, and the correct annotations in json format for each image in another folder. An example of a proper json file: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/object-detection.html

So the question is, how can I use MTurk to get a dataset in the format I need? Is there a way to easily convert their output to JSON files? I have no experience with MTurk whatsoever, so any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

AWS have just released a new feature called "Sagemaker GroundTruth" - where you can send data to Mechanical Turk to get them to create the annotations for you.

https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/groundtruth/

I believe this would fix your issue - you will still be able to use MT, but will no longer need to worry about how the result set comes back. It will integrate straight into your Sagemaker model.